# How to parse value with JSON_VALUE when the string contains double quotes inside

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

I have a column called params which is a json data,

```
{
    "Sender": "Sean Simmons",
    "Event": "Annual meeting",    
    "EventDate": "2023-12-25",  
    "Message": "Attendance is "MANDATORY"!"
}
```

Trying to use JSON_VALUE on the column returns NULL, so i removed the quotes and then it worked, but is there anyway how i can handle this from the database to escape the double quotes of the value and to return it as it is?

Is there anything similar that i can use like the function escape_double_quotes to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, that's not valid json to begin with ... In a valid JSON, the quotes should be escaped, ie `"Message": "Attendence is \"MANDATORY\"!"` I don't think this can be automatically fixed ...

Comment: To render your question more precisely (because I over-read this initially): You have removed the illegal quotes around the word `mandatory` and then it worked. As mentioned in the other comment, your observed behaviour is expected, since the string at hand is not valid JSON.

Comment: @MathiasKemeter this is a row from database table where the message is entered with that word in quotes, so it seems that using json_value is out of the question now for inputs like these...

Comment: @john How do you then assemble the JSON string? If you retrieve parts of it from the database (or somewhere else), you will need to take care of escaping while assembling the string. This can be as easy as just using find & replace.